# Copy columns from one dataframe to another on rows with same date

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
Date        value
2020-03-01    A
2020-03-02    B
2020-03-03    C
2020-03-04    D
```

df2

```
Date        value
2020-02-25    F
2020-02-26    F
2020-02-27    F
2020-02-28    F
2020-02-29    F
2020-03-01    K
2020-03-02    L
2020-03-03    M
2020-03-04    N
```

And I want to copy the values from df2 to df1 on the rows with the same date. The result would be:

```
2020-03-01    K
2020-03-02    L
2020-03-03    M
2020-03-04    N
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Regards

Comment: Maybe just `df2[df2['Date'].isin(df1['Date']))` ?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')`

Comment: `df2.merge(df1['Date'])`

Comment: But TBH, this question is still ambiguous.  There are likely better answers if we had more information.  Like, do you want to keep all the columns of `df1` while just replacing the column values of `df2` and reindexing by the dates from `df2`?  Is `Date` the index of each dataframe?  Anyway, hope what is here in the comments is helpful enough.

Comment: I want to replace the column value from df1 with the values from df2 where the Date is equal. No, Date is not the index

Comment: Also, the start dates are not the same, but all the dates in df1 are in df2. Therefore, I just want to replace all those dates from df1 with the dates from df2